# How to prove cosine distance does not satisfy triangle inequality metric in Euclidean space

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, triangle-inequality

I am trying yo prove cosine distance doesn't satisfy metric rule

i know
$$cosine \ distance = D(x,y)=1−S(x,y) = 1- \frac{x⋅y}{||x||||y||}$$

and able to proof cosine distance indeed satisfy other 3 matric rules
$$dc(d1,d2)⩾0$$
$$dc(d1,d1)=0 $$
$$dc(d1,d2)=dc(d2,d1)$$
But I am wondering in what circumstance will cosine distance breaks triangle inequality metric? rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's only a distance if you restrict it to a sphere centered at the origin. Otherwise, any two points that lie on the same half-line starting at the origin will have zero distance. This is not compatible with the axioms of distance; no distinct point can have zero distance.

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity is purely dictated by the "Cosine" angle. Consider 2 vectors A and B which have an angle of 190 (i.e. 3rd quadrant). Similarly B and C have 190. Thus A and C have 380 = 20 degrees.

COS(A and C) is +ve whereas COS(A and B) and COS(B and C) have -ve sum.

This violates triangular law.

I just used similarity. But I think you can work out similarly for the Distance as well.